# Android camera open delays activity load

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to open camera and display using `SurfaceView`. This delays the loading of the activity for a really long time. So I'm wondering what are the best practices of opening camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html :

> Getting an instance of the Camera object is the first step in the
>   process of directly controlling the camera. As Android's own Camera
>   application does, the recommended way to access the camera is to open
>   Camera on a separate thread that's launched from onCreate(). This
>   approach is a good idea since it can take a while and might bog down
>   the UI thread. In a more basic implementation, opening the camera can
>   be deferred to the onResume() method to facilitate code reuse and keep
>   the flow of control simple.

So the official recommendation is to use a separate thread.  This will mean modifying the activity to be able to deal with a state where the camera isn't open yet, and could even fail to open entirely.

If you aren't comfortable with multithreading and Android app development, it's probably best to just let the Activity start stall.  On most devices the camera opens very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

While it's very difficult to make the camera start faster, you can make the `Activity` start faster by offloading `camera.open()` onto a background thread via an `AsyncTask` or some other method. You can also delay the `camera.open()` call by some arbitrary number of milliseconds after `onResume()`, so that the `Activity` is already visible before camera loading happens.

I don't recommend the AsyncTask method -- making camera loading an asynchronous operation is very prone to errors.

The latter method is also pretty useless as the camera won't be usable until after it loads anyway.